# Will a Corsair H75 cooler be enough to cool a Core i7 7700?

Tags: processor, desktop

I am looking to acquire a Core i7 7700 (non k) in a week or so.

My current build:

- MSI Radeon RX 570 4GB ARMOR OC Edition
- MSI KRAIT B250 Motherboard
- Pentium G4600 @ 3.6 GHz
- Corsair H75 AIO Watercooler
- 8GB DDR4 RAM @ 2133 MHz
- 240GB Gigabyte SSD
- 2 500GB Seagate HDDs

I have searched online on forums, etc., but most of the sites are people asking about the 7700k variant. So my worry is that the H75 will not be strong enough to cool the 7700. Will I have to get a new CPU cooler or should it be strong enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, So I went ahead and bought the CPU, and honestly it runs just fine.

Temps are around 25'C on idle, and up to 40'C in game. In a hot environment it goes up to 55, but have not seen it go any higher than that.